# Captcha in mobile application and web application

Tags: captcha, mobile-application

I have read some web site that captcha is not needed in mobile application.

I have some doubts.

Why captcha is needed in a web application and not needed in a mobile  that access the same application?

Comment: BTW: You read this somewhere. Did the source not give a hint as to *why*?

Comment: links please i also need ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, it is relatively simple to create a bot to crawl the web (*including web applications*) and submit forms. This is where a classic CAPTCHA solution comes in.

**It is comparatively harder to automate data submission within native apps.** This is due to the fact that you cannot just write an automated script to discover `<form>` elements within the *source code* and then *mimic form submission*. Also, you'll need to (purchase and) install the application (on a physical device or in a simulator).

As a side note: web applications for mobile devices can do a lot to make the CAPTCHA process simpler. [Different](http://accessibiliteweb.com/stuff/captcha-slider.html) [versions](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1138) of [slider](http://halfblog.net/another-variation-on-the-slider-captcha) CAPTCHA's come to mind.

Comment: That's incorrect. It's *much* easier to do it for a mobile app as they usually talk to a REST API (or some other well-defined API), you don't even need a scraper.

Comment: @AlexB a little old now but still relevant, can you not send a post the same way one would use a restful api? I don't see how it's easier... A salted hash of the form information would prevent the risk of rest replay.

Comment: @Tohid I'm still looking for one!